# Creating a mixed python data structure by iterating over a list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary

I need to feed data to an API which either creates or deletes users from a system.The syntax for the payload is as follows:

```
b.User.create([{'user': {'name': 'kylie','full_name': 'kylie'}, 
                'password': {'is_encrypted': True, 'password': 'letmein'}, 
                'perms': [{'partition': '/Common', 'role': 'USER_ROLE_GUEST'}], 
                'login_shell': '/sbin/nologin'}])

b.User.delete(['ron'])
```

As is evident,the create user payload is a list of dictionaries which in turn consists of dictionaries.The delete payload is just a simple list of names.

My sample input data is a list of list which is as follows:

```
[['NEW','kylie','OPERATOR','/sbin/nologin'],['DELETE', 'ron', 'ADMINISTRATOR', '/sbin/bash'],['NEW','jessie','GUEST','sbin/nologin']]
```

Some points to be noted :

1. NEW refers to users to be created and DELETE refers to users to be deleted
2. Password is encrypted boolean value,password and partition values are always fixed and need not be taken from input and are same as in the example.

what is the best way of iterating through my input data to create this payload ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate the input data, like this

```
data = [['NEW', 'kylie', 'OPERATOR', '/sbin/nologin'],
        ['DELETE', 'ron', 'ADMINISTRATOR', '/sbin/bash'],
        ['NEW', 'jessie', 'GUEST', 'sbin/nologin']]

for record in data:
    if record[0] == 'NEW':
        b.USER.create([get_user_object(*record[1:])])
    else:
        b.USER.delete([record[1]])
```

And you can implement `get_user_object`, like this

```
def get_user_object(name, role, shell):
    return {
        'user': {
            'name': name,
            'full_name': name
        },
        'password': {
            'is_encrypted': True,
            'password': 'letmein'
        },
        'perms': [{
            'partition': '/Common',
            'role': role
        }],
        'login_shell': shell
    }
```

Comment: This is really awesome..just to understand why is the * needed while calling the get_user_object funtion

Comment: @Amistad `record[1:]` ll create a sublist and the elements of the sublist should be passed one by one to `get_user_object` as parameter. So, [we use * to unpack the arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: similar to *args and **kwargs i see always in django code ?

Comment: @Amistad Yes... That is for packing... Here we do the inverse of it. Please check the doc link I mentioned in the last comment. This has been explained there.

Comment: yes..i went through that..thanks so much for the answer and explaining this to me..